# Space between textview and drawable icon

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, textview

I'm facing problems with the position of an icon. I've set that icon as drawableLeft of a TextView, this is working fine but, if I set the TextView's gravity to center_horizontal, then a padding space appears between the icon and the text. The code is as follows:

```
<TextView
    style="@style/BaseText.White.Bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_text"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_text"
    android:text="@string/text"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_small"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_big"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_big"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:drawablePadding="0dp"/>
```

What do I have to do to ensure that the icon is shown at the text's left side but horizontally centered?
I've make two screenshots to show you the difference when adding or removing the icon's gravity. 
When the textview's gravity is not set, the result is as follows:
[image]

But, when the gravity is added, then a padding appears between the text and the icon:
[image]
Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `android:gravity="center"`.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried as you said, but with no luck :(

Comment: @FVod please share screen of your desired output

Comment: I've edited the post to add two snapshots

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Try to give `android:gravity="center"` to `Text View`. Also add `android:layout_width="wrap_content" and   android:layout_height="wrap_content"` properties in `Text View`.

**Refer this.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:drawableLeft="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:drawablePadding="0dp"
        android:drawableStart="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:text="TestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTestingTesting" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

> This is what it showing.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The layout_width and height are set to wrap_content in the style, anyway, I have tried the way you say but the result doesn't change :(

Comment: Can you share screen what you exactly want so that i can suggest you. **Because using Gravity Center it will not show any space between icon and text and that is what you want**

Comment: @FVod So you want output as 1 st screen or 2 nd screen ?

Comment: But if you remove some Testing in order to make a shorten second line (and add some space between words) you'll see that depending on the device's width the space between the text and the icon will change, at least this is what is happening to me.

Comment: @FVod Nope the `Text View` will not affect it's size in different devices. make it wrap content height and width will enough. if your design is too complicated then it affect otherwise not. So make your text size to `20sp` or more. **Btw accept and up-vote** the answer if somewhere it helped you.

Answer (score 6):

Only add android:drawablePadding="10dp" field in your text view refer the coad

```
 <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add New Address"
        android:textAppearance="@style/Title"
        android:id="@+id/tvAddNewAddress"
        android:drawablePadding="20dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:drawableStart="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"
        />
```